# Is there a way to override the serialization error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a simple class for the POST request body:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(PostRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class PostRequest
{
    [Required]
    public String String { get; set; }
}
```

If I send an int instead of a string, the following error message is returned:

> "$.string": [
> "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $.string | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 13."]
> }

I don't feel like exposing what happens under the hood is right. Is there a way to return a generic "The field String is invalid" message?

Comment: What do you think this is exposing? That your backend is processing the JSON before attempting to use it? That's hardly going to come as news to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error comes from `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` inside [SystemTextJsonInputFormatter](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet/blob/main/src/aspnetcore/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.cs) durring desrializing request body into the model and you can disable it like below:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false);
```

And you will relieve error message like this:

```json
{
  "$.string": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

You can also customize error message and get rid of `$.` like below:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    //we need to call this original factory inside our custom factory
    var originalFactory = o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory;
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        //get all the keys prefixed with $. (which should be related to json errors)
        var jsonPathKeys = context.ModelState.Keys.Where(e => e.StartsWith("$.")).ToList();
        foreach (var key in jsonPathKeys)
        {
            var normalizedKey = key.Substring(2);
            foreach (var error in context.ModelState[key].Errors)
            {
                if (error.Exception != null)
                {
                    context.ModelState.TryAddModelException(normalizedKey, error.Exception);
                }
                context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(normalizedKey, "The provided value is not valid.");
            }
            context.ModelState.Remove(key);
        }
        return originalFactory(context);
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but maybe this will help you. Paste this code at the very beginning of the method:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
 {
     return BadRequest();
 }
```